# How do I get Souls?

Tags: terraria

A lot of the cool new recipes in patch 1.1 I've found out via asking the Guide require some sort of Soul, of which there appear to be numerous different types. For example:

- Soul of Light
- Soul of Night
- Soul of Might
- Soul of Fright

I've played for a couple hours, and I've yet to find a single one of *any* type of Soul. How do I get them? Do I maybe need a special item to extract them from slain monsters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Souls items do not need any sort of item to extract them from monsters. They are drops from specific Hard Mode enemies.

Once you have defeated the Wall of Flesh and entered Hard Mode, you can get those souls from the following enemies:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Soul Name    |                      Enemy                      |                                  Enemy Location                                   |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Soul of Night  | Any enemy in the Underground Corruption/Crimson | Underground Corruption/Crimson                                                    |
| Soul of Light  | Any enemy in the Underground Hallow             | Underground Hallow                                                                |
| Soul of Flight | Wyvern                                          | High Altitudes (Look for harpies)                                                 |
| Soul of Might  | The Destroyer                                   | Use a Mechanical Worm at night                                                    |
| Soul of Sight  | The Twins                                       | Use a Mechanical Eye at night                                                     |
| Soul of Fright | Skeletron Prime                                 | Use a Mechanical Skull at night                                                   |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For each of the bosses, there is also a chance each night that they will spawn on their own (similar to the Eye of Cthulu).

For the Souls of Night and Light, note that it does not have to be an enemy from that biome. Any enemy that dies in that the appropriate corrupted biome has a chance to drop a soul. For example, if I have Underground Hallow and underground Corruption biomes right next to each other and I lure an enemy from the Hallow into the Corruption, it has a chance to drop a Soul of Night.

Answer (score 14):

Soul of Flight: Wyvern
Soul of Fright: Skeletron Prime, Hardmode Skeletron
Soul of Light: Hallowed enemies (Illuminated Slime, etc)
Soul of Might: Destroyer, Hardmode Eater of Worlds
Soul of Night: Corrupted enemies (Green Jellyfish, Eater of Souls, etc.)
Soul of Sight: The Twins (Spazmatism and Retinazer) Hardmode Eye of Cthulu

Crafting recipes for the mechanical summoning totems are easliy gotten from The Guide by showing him Iron or Copper bars.

It should also be noted that in order for these monsters to appear, one must first defeat the Wall of Flesh.

Comment: This answer's complete and correct.  Though it should be noted that the mobs required for Souls of Light and Night appear only in the underground Corruption/ Hallow, in hardmode, and also that normal enemies that spawn in such biomes have a chance of dropping them, as well.

Comment: As of the current patch *any* enemy in the underground corruption, including those from other biomes, can drop a soul of night. Similarly with the underground hallow.Similarly, killing underground corruption mobs in other biomes will not drop a soul of night.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, which of the souls have you gathered? What do you know? It's all good questions. And I have found all souls in PC but none in Mobile (cuz I'm not in Hardmode in Mobile).

Kill Wyverns in the sky in Hardmode for Souls of Flight.(these are required in order to craft wings) They spawn among Harpies, but are much rarer.

In Underground Corruption/Crimson kill monsters inside it in Hardmode to aquire Souls of Night!

Next is Light, which are dropped by monsters in the Underground Hallow.(full name: Soul of Light)

Then for the other souls: Soul of Might is dropped by Destroyer(100%) and rarely the mobile Lepus.

Soul of Fright is gathered from Skeletron Prime, and Souls of Sight are dropped by The Twins.

There is also a Console/mobile Soul Dropped by the Console/Mobile Ocram called souls of Blight.(Ocram is tricky, so be prepared)

Answer (score -1):

The souls can be farmed from new mobs after you beat wall of flesh.

So far I have found soul of flight witch is collected from dragons. I found the dragons on my path I made for collecting stars, near the top of the world, where grav has less effect.

Comment: The Dragons are known as **Wyverns** in game, even if they do look like Eastern Dragons.

Answer (score -2):

Souls of Light and Night are found from defeating enemies in the Underground Hallow and Underground Corruption/Crimson respectively after defeating the Wall of Flesh and entering hardmode. Souls of Might are from a boss called the Destroyer. Souls of Fright are from a boss called Skeletron Prime.

And there are 2 types of souls you haven't seen: Souls of Sight (hardmode boss: The Twins) and Souls of Flight, which you get from [Wyverns](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wyvern/), which spawn in the Sky layer during Hardmode (after defeating the Wall of Flesh).

So, basically:

- Light: Hallow
- Night: Corruption/Crimson
- Might: The destroyer
- Fright: Skeletron Prime
- Sight: The Twins
- Flight: Wyverns

(quick note in case you don't know: Hallow is a happy-themed biome that spawns at hardmode. However, the unicorns and pixies still try to kill you, so don't be fooled)